# last_insert_id() inserts all id's from table to table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Im trying to insert one (the last one) newest entry from customers table into orders table.
With `last_insert_id()` in the query it inserts orders to all customers.

SQL query:

```
INSERT INTO orders 
    (CusID, ProdID) 
    SELECT 
        last_insert_id(CusID), 
        ProdID 
    FROM customers, products;
```

I also tried this:

```
INSERT INTO orders 
    (CusID, ProdID) 
    SELECT 
        CusID, 
        ProdID 
    FROM 
        customers 
    ORDER BY CusID DESC 
    LIMIT 1, 
    products;
```

Which gives syntax error.

Comment: what is the ", products" at the end of the second attempt? It looks like you are trying to join the customers and products tables, but without a join statement?

Comment: I think the logic is wrong. My guess would be something like: `INSERT INTO orders (CusID, ProdID)
SELECT CusID, ProdID FROM customers where cusId=last_insert_id()`. (and I know, that this won't work because of missing products table, where you'd need a join somehow)

Comment: @BenGreen That's the short version of the CROSS JOIN. cf. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Join_(SQL)#Cross_join

Comment: @Dormilich, learn something new every day (the syntax), thanks - I retract my previous comment!